# Getting to Sembach, Germany from Frankfurt Airport

Tags: germany, routes, fra

What would be the best way to get from Frankfurt Airport (FRA) to Sembach in Germany (and back), assuming that renting a car at airport and driving there directly is not an option.

Google Maps [tells me](https://goo.gl/maps/JsYYv), that the best (fastest, the smallest number of interconnections) is to take two trains and a taxi for a final part of journey and that the entire travel will take about three hours. Is there anything bit better?

What would be an estimate cost of such travel?

Additional question: If renting a car at the airport would be an option (it certainly is the fastest option -- 1 hour of travelling) then approximatelly how much money do I need to have for renting any car (I'll be travelling alone) for two days with pickup and return points at Fraport?

Comment: Your additional question you can answer yourself, either using the hire car companies site, or a car-hire comparison, like the one on Skyscanner.

Comment: It seems you want to travel on a weekend? You should state this in the question if it is the case.

Comment: You need to supply us with a day and time to give you answers. But there are definitely busses going to Sembach from Kaiserslautern, which seems to be the next major train station: http://fahrplanauskunft.vrn.de/vrn/FILELOAD?Filename=b_w_55EED7440.pdf - whether it is a feasible option depends on the day and time of the day.  Google maps is pretty bad in terms of non-train public transportation in Germany as public transportation authorities often do not want to share their data with Google.

Comment: @DCTLib I don't have exact dates for my trip yet. However, your comment seems to me like a fully-featured answer, so consider re-editing it to an answer. I don't think, if I can get something better than that.

Comment: @chirlu Nope, your guessing / assumptions are unfortunately incorrect. I'm talking about two days, because I'm considering taking part in two days long course in Sembach. This means, that this will most certainly take place during office days, not during weekend, although I don't have any fixed dates right, as I stated in comment to _DCTLib_, except for the fact, that this should take places in November or December.

Comment: @trejder: It was based on the duration of three hours and the need to take a taxi, but apparently Google Maps just didn't give you the optimal relation. Anyway, the answer covers weekdays and weekends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best option is to use [German Railway's journey planner](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query2.exe/en) (in English), since they also cover the bus lines between Kaiserslautern and Sembach. Just search for connections from 'FRA Frankfurt Airport' to 'Sembach Ortsmitte' (Sembach village centre).

Basically, there are fairly regular bus connections between Kaiserslautern and Sembach Monday through Friday. Saturday and Sunday, you are limited to a concept called 'Ruftaxi' in German, which is noted as 'ALT' in the journey planner. I don't know if a similar concept is known in other countries, but this is a bus line operated by taxis on demand. The taxis operate the line according to a schedule (much like a bus line), you only pay the bus fare, but you have to order a ride usually at least 60 minutes before departure. The journey planner explains this an gives you the correct phone number, but only in German even if you use the English language version.

For example: 'Ruftaxi, Tel.: 06303/123456, Anmeldung mind. 60 Min vor Abfahrt' means 'callable taxi, phone: 06303/123456, registration at least 60 minutes before departure'.

The fastest connection are 2 hours and 20 minutes.